# Get field name that err's in Go json unmarshal

Tags: json, go

I have some big json files that are slightly different in the types that the fields contain.

```
{ "a":"1" }
```

vs.

```
{ "a":1 }
```

When I unmarshal the second I get:

```
cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string
```

However since these jsons are large I would like to have the actual field that is in error so I can fix them. The [`UnmarshalTypeError`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#UnmarshalFieldError) does not hold the Struct's field type.

Does anybody know of a way to get to field name? (not debugging I have a lot of different fields that err)

[EDIT]
I know how to solve the type conversion. What I need is a method to see what fields I need to apply that conversion to.

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing the Go maintainers would be willing to fix. I've just filed [Bug 8254](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8254) against the encoding/json package for you.

Comment: In the future, you might want to take a question that's so obviously a feature request/bug report to the [golang-nuts Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts), where you have a high likelihood of one of the Go development team seeing it.

Comment: @KenBloom: thanks, but for me it was not clear (yet) this could not be achieved in another way than editing language packages. Did too much Python lately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.

However, to fix your problem, there is multiple solutions:

- Dive into the `json.Unmarshal` source code to change its working and add the information you need: copy the function to a local package, do your edits, and use this function
- Use a thrid-party tool to help you, for example a JSON validator compatible with [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/): here is an [online example](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/), there is probably some better-suited tool

Comment: If you dive into json.Unmarshal and edit it, you're probably best off submitting a patch to Google so all can benefit. You can probably attach it right to [bug 8254](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8254).

Answer (score 2):

Now the [UnmarshalTypeError](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#UnmarshalTypeError), contains the field name.